# Ошибка при запуске нового проекта

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Здравствуйте. Установил Qt Creator Community, дальше попытался создать новое приложение (Qt Widgets Application), не зная, возможно не то выбрал, далее везде нажимал "next", все оставил по умолчанию, но после нажатия кнопки "RUN" возникла ошибка:

> Error while building/deploying project untitled1 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.4.1 GCC 64bit)

Что она означает и как ее исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте или полностью переконфигурить проект, или выйти, прибить все файлы *.user в папке проекта, снова войти и открыть проект.

Comment: я думаю, то что выделено желтым, это не все сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: тут написано просто что произошла ошибка во время сборки/развертки проекта untitled1 и выведен набор, используемый для сборки, тут мало информации

Comment: Вот все что в консоли написано: 13:50:04: Configuration is faulty. Check the Issues view for details.
Error while building/deploying project untitled1 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.4.1 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"